# how can I display 'processing' inside jquery datatable?

Tags: datatables, angular-datatables

I'm using jquery datatables(angular datatables) with server side processing, the message 'processing' is above the table. I can change the position through sDOM (lfrtip), but is it possible to make it inside the datatable(put p into t)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes...there are a few ways you can do this. I like to use a "loading gif". So, your HTML looks like this:

```
<table  id="main_index">
<img id="loading_gif" src="images/ajax-loader.gif"> <!--this is your loading image or div-->
</table>
```

Then you want this .gif to be hidden once the table loads. You use datatables callback function for this. For example:

```
$("#main_compare").DataTable({
//all of your other datatables configuration followed by a comma then...
"drawCallback": function(settings, json) {
            $('#loading_gif').hide(); //hides the loading image once table is loaded
            //do anything else you want to have happen only once the table is loaded
                }
})
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, I think this is what you're looking for.

If you want a message to appear within the area of the table while it's loading, you use this structure:

```
<table  id="main_index">
    <div id="table_processing">Whatever text you want</div> 
    </table>
```

You can then hide this using the code from my original answer to hide this div when the table loads.

Comment: thanks for your answer @jonmrich,  I am not very clear about the solution. I don't want to insert another element. I've replaced the 'processing' message with a loading gif, just want it to be displayed in the right place.

Comment: for my datatable, I want to put it inside the table element

Comment: My edited answer will do exactly what you need. It puts the text inside the table until you remove it when the table loads

Answer (score 0):

1. The `processing` option needs to be set to true
   and
2. In the `sDom` option the letter `r` was needed.

   ```
   var options = {  
     "sDom": 'prtp',  
     "processing": true,  
     "serverSide": true,  
     "ajax": "/path/to/my/ajax.php"  
   }  
   var oTable = $('.datatables').dataTable(options);
   ```